# Should dependant assemblies of a test assembly be in the same directory?

Tags: nunit

I have an error with NUnit GUI (2.5.10.11092) :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.10.11092, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77'

this dll is in this folder : "C:\Dev\Libs\nunit.framework.dll"

If I copy this dll in the same directory than the assembly I want to test, it works fine but I don't want to copy this `nunit.framework dll`.

Is there any way solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need all dependent assemblies to be in the same directory or in the GAC.
Note this is a simplified explanation of the issue. You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx)

The solution:
Create an output directory for your assemblies and mark nunit.framework.dll with "copy local = true" in Visual Studio properties window. This will copy nunit assembly on every successful build to the same directory as your test assembly.